# Ghost directories/files with php?

Tags: php, directory

I was wondering how Wordpress and other random forums and sites, like facebook, create like phantom directories? Eg, a blog might have `http://www.joesblog.com/2010/11/12/this-is-my-post.php`

Does that file and directory resource actually exist? Also, how does Facebook, for example, have like `http://www.facebook.com/-usernamehere-` ? Is that a physical directory, or is it simply a scripting trick? How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: This has been asked here many times before.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rewrite  You're looking for topics related to mod_rewrite, or URL rewriting in general.

Comment: Another keyword you can google for is "pretty URLs".

Comment: Quick yes or no question: Can PHP do this, or is it a server thing? e.g. Apache or IIS. Also, would a tracker such as Google Analytics pick up this rewrite?

Comment: The web server is a required part of the equation, since it handles the initial URLs.

Comment: @BlackWraith You can achieve this in apache by using mod_rewrite configured in a .htaccess file. I also updated my answer to reflect your question about implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of functionality is normally achieved by instructing the web server to "link" certain URL patterns to a specific controller.

See [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess), for example.

EDIT: This article on [Rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) might also help.

So no, no directories actually exist. The web server receives a request for a specific URI and redirects that request to a delegated controller (that can be a PHP script, for example) that in turn returns a result based on the URI and action requested by the user.

PHP can certainly handle this, but it's the web server that needs to be instructed on how to handle those types of request.
If you're using apache you might want to take a look at some [mod_rewrite tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite%20tutorial).